# Plugin installation not possible / FTP credentials in WP-config

Tags: ftp

I have an issue with one of my Wordpress installations.

When I try to install a plugin, WP asks for my FTP credentials. I entered them but neither FTPs nor FTP are working - but the credentials are 100% correct.

I opened up the wp-config.php and pasted the configuration in the file.

When I now want to install a plugin I still see the screen where the FTP data must be entered, its greyed out with the info from the WP config file but with an error text that the connection to the FTP could not be established.

Does anybody know if this is server setting or what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a question better suited for your hosting company :) Seems to me like a setting is off on your server.

Comment: Maybe a permissions issue?  Your credentials maybe correct, but the FTP user may not have permission to create a folder, for example.  Usually your host provides tools such a CPanel, which allow you to manage FTP users - perhaps check if such a tool is available and review permissions.  But ultimatly I agree with @cristian.raiber, this is most likly a server/host fault and not WP.

Comment: Try using "localhost" for the hostname. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: I switched to ftp_method "direct" - now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

solved it.