# To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web > server

Tags: plugins, themes, installation, ftp

Please help me, I installed WordPress locally to learn how to make sites but after my installation when I wanted to install a WordPress elementor plugin I receive this message:

> To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web
>   server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not
>   remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

i don't know how to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plugin installation not possible / FTP credentials in WP-config](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180341/plugin-installation-not-possible-ftp-credentials-in-wp-config)

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the following Line before `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */` in `wp-config.php` file.

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

Comment: That solution _does work_, but it does _not explain why_ and is also _not the expected approach for a WP Install_. This issue only surges in installs that are _wrongly_ hardened or have other problems with file permissions. The _right_ solution instead is to understand file permissions. Set WordPress directory and file permissions to allow your **webserver's** user account execute+read+write access. (Typically this means setting permissions 0775 for directories and 0664 for files.) What you are doing with define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' ); is de-facto telling WP to bypass all security.